# how to activate only Left-hand match suggestions on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to activate only Left-hand match suggestions on VSCode Editor.

For example, my custom snippet contains "time_period" and "period_date".
When I type "pe", both of two are show on suggestions.

However, I want VSCode to show only "period_date".

Any solutions?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ynAD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex search.

Enable it with `Alt + R` on Windows/Linux, `Cmd + Option + R` on Mac, or simply by clicking on the icon:
[image]

From there, you can use `^period` to match the start of the line.

Comment: thank you but I want to change the result of suggestion (auto completion) and not search as I uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: @youarethesucculent Autocomplete is a feature of IntelliSense, and it can not be configured much in VSCode.

Comment: Closest setting I can think of is `editor.suggest.matchOnWordStartOnly` which would only match **period** when it is a separate word. E.g. it would be matched in **time_period** or **timePeriod**, but not in **timeperiod**.